# using ajax call to empty the div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Making a ajax, so when i click on this Link1 Button, i need to empty the contents in the products_list div

```
<button type="w3-button">Link1</button>
```

Please help me on how to make a ajax call when clicking `link1` button it empty the products in `product_list`

The below code contains a javascript to clear the contents of products_list but it do not work

PHP File

```
 <?php
session_start(); //start session
include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Stores</title>
<link href="style/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h3>Products</h3>
</div>

<script>
$(document).on("click", ".w3-button", function() {
  $('.products-wrp').html('')
 // $("#products_list").html();
});</script>
<?php
//List products from database
$results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code, product_image, product_price FROM products_list");
//Display fetched records as you please

$products_list =  '<ul id ="products_list" class="products-wrp">';

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$products_list .= <<<EOT
<li>
<form class="form-item">
<h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
<div>
<img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
</div>
<div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
</form>
</li>
EOT;

}
$products_list .= '</ul></div>';
echo $products_list;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try $('.products-wrp').empty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Code below that will empty the div On Failure on Ajax Request -

```js
function getFailOutput() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'myAjax.php',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(data, response);
            $('#output').html(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            //Empty Output  Div ON Error Returned From Ajax Request
            $('#output').html('');
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="return getSuccessOutput();"> test success </a> | <a href="#" onclick="return getFailOutput(); return false;"> test failure</a>
<div id="output">waiting for action</div>
```

Comment: @prog yes sure. you can use same line of code in success as well. you can use it anywhere its jquery function.